# How does Android Volley stop/cleanup its dispatcher threads

Tags: android, android-volley

Looking at [the source code of the Volley library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley), I'm curious of how exactly does the "cleanup" of the dispatcher threads work. A `RequestQueue` contains one `CacheDispatcher` instance and an array of `NetworkDispatcher` instances. Both of these dispatcher classes extend `Thread` and are started as soon as they are created. After that, they run in an infinite loop until their `quit()` methods are called.

My question is, how are those threads actually stopped (i.e. what, if anything, prevents them from running indefinitely until the system kills the app), for example when the user leaves the application. The `quit()` methods of the dispatchers is called only from the RequestQueues `stop()` method, but that method itself isn't called from anywhere in the Volley, aside from the `start()` method to cleanup the possible previous dispatchers before initializing the new ones.

What I am sort of aiming at with the question is **how much of an issue** are the idle threads, and **how they behave** when the task (i.e. a group of activities) goes from the foreground to the background and hangs around for a while. Androids task switcher can hold quite a bit of apps (altough some of them might have been ejected/stopped), and most of them presumably use libs like volley/okhttp/picasso which have their thread pools. In theory that could add up to quite a lot of threads (albeit idle).

I understand this is a fairly low-level question and would probably require a lot of theory to explain correctly, if someone can provide a satisfactory answer touching on the **bold** stuff above, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I've discovered that, during instrumented testing when the queue gets started/stopped/recreated repeatedly, I can end up with dozens of NetworkDispatcher objects sitting in memory by the end of the run. It wouldn't be a big deal except that they hold on to requests which hold on to listeners which ultimately leak quite a bit of memory.

Comment: Yeah, I figured something like that was the case. I've edited the question to provide further info.